# Issue Getting Div to Hug up close to another

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have 6 Divs within a container Div. These divs have to be aligned a certain way for a clients needs. I've taken the basic layout for the customer website I'm working on and created a sample to be posted here. I have a regular CSS file and a mobile CSS file. When in mobile view the Divs will be aligned in sequential order 1-6. When in the regular view, Divs 1, 3, 4, and 5 will be aligned to the right. Divs 2 and 6 will be aligned to the left. I need div 6 to hug the bottom of div 2 with the exception of about 10px. With my current code the Divs have a huge gap between them and 6 gets pushed further down the page with the more content the right side Divs have. All of these Divs have dynamic content that can make them increase or decrease in the amount of shown content. How can I get Div 6 to ignore the right side Divs and hug Div 2 without screwing up how these condense and appear in mobile? (You can just resize your browser window for the mobile version to appear with this code.)

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
/*
exampleCSS.css
*/
#containerDiv {
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

#div1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
}

#div2 {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 65%;
    float: left;
}

#div3 {
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: green;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
}

#div4 {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}

#div5 {
    border: 1px solid purple;
    background-color: purple;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}

#div6 {
    border: 1px solid pink;
    background-color: pink;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 65%;
    float: left;
}

/*
exampleCSSMobile.css
*/
#containerDiv {
    width: 100%;
}

#div1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

#div2 {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

#div3 {
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: green;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

#div4 {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

#div5 {
    border: 1px solid purple;
    background-color: purple;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

#div6 {
    border: 1px solid pink;
    background-color: pink;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example HTML</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="exampleCSSMobile.css" media="(max-width: 940px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="exampleCSS.css" media="(min-width: 940px)" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="containerDiv">
            <div id="div1"><p>Test 1 Lorem Ipsum.</p></div>
            <div id="div2"><p>Test 2 Lorem Ipsum. Prion gravida nibh vel velit auctor 
                            aliquet. Aenean solicitudin, lorem quis bibendum 
                            auctor, nisi elit consquat ipsum, nec sagittas sem 
                            nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate 
                            cursus a sit neque. Suspendisse in orci enim. Lorem Ipsum. Prion gravida nibh vel velit auctor 
                            aliquet. Aenean solicitudin, lorem quis bibendum 
                            auctor, nisi elit consquat ipsum, nec sagittas sem 
                            nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate 
                            cursus a sit neque. Suspendisse in orci enim. Lorem Ipsum. Prion gravida nibh vel velit auctor 
                            aliquet. Aenean solicitudin, lorem quis bibendum 
                            auctor, nisi elit consquat ipsum, nec sagittas sem 
                            nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate 
                            cursus a sit neque. Suspendisse in orci enim. Lorem Ipsum. Prion gravida nibh vel velit auctor 
                            aliquet. Aenean solicitudin, lorem quis bibendum 
                            auctor, nisi elit consquat ipsum, nec sagittas sem 
                            nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate 
                            cursus a sit neque. Suspendisse in orci enim.</p></div>
            <div id="div3"><p>Test 3 Lorem Ipsum. Prion gravida nibh vel velit auctor 
                            aliquet. Aenean solicitudin, lorem quis bibendum 
                            auctor, nisi elit consquat ipsum, nec sagittas sem 
                            nibh id elit. </p></div>
            <div id="div4"><p>Test 4 Lorem Ipsum. Prion gravida nibh vel velit auctor 
                            aliquet. Aenean solicitudin, lorem quis bibendum 
                            auctor, nisi elit consquat ipsum, nec sagittas sem 
                            nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate 
                            cursus a sit neque. Suspendisse in orci enim.</p></div>
            <div id="div5"><p>Test 5 Lorem Ipsum. Prion gravida nibh vel velit auctor 
                            aliquet. Aenean solicitudin, lorem quis bibendum 
                            auctor, nisi elit consquat ipsum, nec sagittas sem 
                            nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate 
                            cursus a sit neque. Suspendisse in orci enim.</p></div>
            <div id="div6"><p>Test 6 Lorem Ipsum. Prion gravida nibh vel velit auctor 
                            aliquet. Aenean solicitudin, lorem quis bibendum 
                            auctor, nisi elit consquat ipsum, nec sagittas sem 
                            nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate 
                            cursus a sit neque. Suspendisse in orci enim. Lorem Ipsum. Prion gravida nibh vel velit auctor 
                            aliquet. Aenean solicitudin, lorem quis bibendum 
                            auctor, nisi elit consquat ipsum, nec sagittas sem 
                            nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate 
                            cursus a sit neque. Suspendisse in orci enim. Lorem Ipsum. Prion gravida nibh vel velit auctor 
                            aliquet. Aenean solicitudin, lorem quis bibendum 
                            auctor, nisi elit consquat ipsum, nec sagittas sem 
                            nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate 
                            cursus a sit neque. Suspendisse in orci enim. Lorem Ipsum. Prion gravida nibh vel velit auctor 
                            aliquet. Aenean solicitudin, lorem quis bibendum 
                            auctor, nisi elit consquat ipsum, nec sagittas sem 
                            nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate 
                            cursus a sit neque. Suspendisse in orci enim. Lorem Ipsum. Prion gravida nibh vel velit auctor 
                            aliquet. Aenean solicitudin, lorem quis bibendum 
                            auctor, nisi elit consquat ipsum, nec sagittas sem 
                            nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate 
                            cursus a sit neque. Suspendisse in orci enim.</p></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Image of the example with the space between 2 and 6:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A floated element will move as far to the left or right as it can **in the position where it was originally**(this is important #1).

So put in this way:

We have 2 div

```
<div class="div5">div5</div>
<div class="div6">div6</div>

.div-blue{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: blue;
}

.div-red{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background: red;
}
```

without `float` they'll be one below the other

[image]

If we `float: right` the `div5`, the `div6` be positioned on the line when it was the `div5`,

`/*the lines are just for illustrate*/`

[image]

So if now we `float: left` the `div6` it will move as far to the left as it can, "**in this line**" (see #1 above), so if `div5` change its line, `div6` will follow it.

Now let's add other div into the equation

```
<div class="div4">div4</div>
<div class="div5">div5</div>
<div class="div6">div6</div>

.div-gree{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background: green;

    float:right;
}
```

We have this

[image]

If we set `clear: right` to the `div5`, we are force it to take the line bellow `div4`

[image]

So there you have why happens. [Here the jsfiddle where I code this](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/qvLaL56o/)

**NOW, HOW TO FIX IT**

Just remove the float for the `<div id="div6">` and set `display: inline-block`

like this:

```
#div6 {
    border: 1px solid pink;
    background-color: pink;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 65%;

    /*float: left;*/    /*removed*/

    display: inline-block;  /*added*/
}
```

This will keep the normal behavior for elements without `float` (The elements after the floating element will flow around it.). The `display: inline-block` is for your case to maintain the `margin` of `div2`.

[HERE A JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE WORKING FOR YOUR CASE](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/1rzk5fmj/)

I hope this helps now and in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some javascript for this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var d6Id = document.getElementById( 'div6' ); 
    var d6distanceTop = d6Id.offsetTop; // Get height above div 6

    var d2height = document.getElementById( 'div2' ).clientHeight; // Get height of div 2

    var space = d6distanceTop - 30 - d2height; // 30 for padding top and bottom + 10px margin

    d6Id.style["margin-top"] = "-"+space+"px";
}
```