# "float: right" doesn't put the div on the right side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't understand why I can't get this to work.
I am making this CSS vertical sidemenu and I want it to be in the right side of the window.
So i have the div of the menu and I wrapped it in another div, setting it to float to the right.

Problem is, it's stuck on the left side.
I want to be able to scroll it but leave the rest of the page in the same place.
this is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xQgSm/121/

this is part of the code:

```
<div id="wrap" style="height: 100%; position: absolute; overflow-y: scroll; float: right">
    <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
```

Comment: `#wrap{ right: 0;}` http://jsfiddle.net/xQgSm/122/

Comment: I liked that even more.

Answer (score 4):

You need your wrapper to be `width: 100%` of the page.

Try adding:

```
<div id="wrap" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; overflow-y: scroll;">
```

Comment: it worked. amazing. love this website.
why does it have to be like that?

Comment: Well you are floating the element to the right of the parent element. If your parent element is not set to 100%, it will be the size of the content within it, thus your menu was floated right but the wrapper was only the width of the menu so it appeared to be left.

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer Check out this answer to well understand how the float works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813047/issue-getting-div-to-hug-up-close-to-another/30815117#30815117

Answer (score 1):

Because your element has `position: absolute;`, the correct way is to set the `right` property, e.g:

*CSS:*

```
#wrap{ right: 0;}
```

### -jsFiddle-

Answer (score 1):

Because your #wrap is positioned absolute, it looses the default block behavior, which means it is not 100%-width anymore, but only as wide as its widest child.

So in your case you have 3 possibilities:

- *loose* the position *absolute* **or**
- *position* the #wrap to the *right* **or**
- give it *100%-width* and then float only the #cssmenu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with some rtl and assigning

```
width:100%
```

worked for me. your code also is fixed with it try 
http://jsfiddle.net/ofdqyy4g/